# How to identify Image receive in C-STORE as result of a C-MOVE query

Tags: dicom

I'm making a **C-MOVE** query to the PACS server in the view to receive some Images.
On the other side, I have a server component which accept the **C-STORE** command produced by the PACS server, and receive the images. Both components are in the same application.
Everything good, but now the question:
How can I be sure in my server component, that actually receiving images, that they are the  response to my C-MOVE query?
Another client may have asked the PACS to send me images or series...
Is there any 'transaction identificator'?

Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Look at Part 7 of the DICOM standard http://medical.nema.org/standard.html; section 9.

The C-STORE request should have the Move Originator Message ID (0000,1031) value specified in the message fields. It should match with the Message ID (0000,0110) used to make the C-MOVE request.

Comment: Thx that was exactly what I've missed.
In combining MoveOriginatorApplicationEntityTitle and MoveOriginatorMessageID I can identify if I was the producer of the C-MOVE.
It seam that those attributes are optional and not always returned.